# How to switch to the staggered collection view and to a list view with one item per row in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uikit

I am showing some images in the collection view cells . As of now I am using a simple collection view which shows the items and it is currently showing two items per row . The following code is given below:

```
import UIKit

import MBProgressHUD

class HotViewController: BaseViewController {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets

   @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var filterSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbarHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbarView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    // MARK: - Properties

    let hotViewModel = HotViewModel()
    var hotPhotos = [ImageMeta]()
    var filteredPhotos = [ImageMeta]()

    // MARK: - ViewLifeCycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViewModel()
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Methods

    func setupViewModel()  {
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        hotViewModel.getHotPhotos()

        hotViewModel.getPhotoListDidSucess = { [weak self] list in
            
           guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
            strongSelf.hotPhotos = list
            strongSelf.filteredPhotos = list.filter{$0.in_most_viral == true}

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: strongSelf.view, animated: true)
                strongSelf.collectionView.reloadData()
             
            }
            
        }
        
        hotViewModel.getPhotoListDidFailed = { [weak self] message in
            print("message \(message)")
            guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: strongSelf.view, animated: true)
            }
        }
        
    }
    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func switchValueDidChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func aboutButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showPopUp()
    }
 
}

// MARK: - CollectionViewDataSource


extension HotViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       
        if filterSwitch.isOn && filteredPhotos.count == 0 {
            messageLabel.isHidden = false

        }
        else{
            messageLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        return  (filterSwitch.isOn ? filteredPhotos.count : hotPhotos.count)
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let photo = filterSwitch.isOn ? filteredPhotos[indexPath.row] : hotPhotos[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell : PhotoListCell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
        cell.configureCell(with: photo)

        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                
        let photo = filterSwitch.isOn ? filteredPhotos[indexPath.row] : hotPhotos[indexPath.row]
        
        showDetailedPage(metaData: photo)        
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension HotViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                            layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                            minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat(interitemSpacing)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
            collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                            minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat(lineSpacing)
        }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return getItemSize()
    }
}
```

**I am getting the following result as:**

So in this image you can see 1 and 2 marked in red . What I want is

- A) **on pressing 1 the number of items per row should become 1
  instead of 2**
- B) **on pressing 2 the cells should become staggered
  instead of perfect square .**

Is it possible to achieve using the same collection view ?How can I achieve it using the same collection view  ?

**Here is an example of staggered collection view :**

[image]

**How can I switch to staggered view , list and regular view on button clicks?**

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to add flags and when you click you just reload the collectionView.
and do all the code in the delegates of the collection view ...

Comment: That i know i want to get the staggered view layout and how to restrict only one item per row ?

Comment: Please check  following link. This might help you

https://iosrevisited.blogspot.com/2017/09/toggle-between-listviewuitableview-and.html